# Calling php function with ajax and passing return value to div

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I have a function that adds social buttons to my blog posts , but once i load more posts using ajax I cant figure out how can I call add_social_buttons() and pass the data to div.

I'm not really familiar with ajax , i tried this method :

```
$.ajax({
  type:"POST",
  url:"functions.php",
  data: "social_sharing_buttons()",
  success: function(data){
  $('.pp').html(data);
  }
```

but it seems that it tries to invoke some totally other function Fatal error: Call to undefined function add_action().

Comment: What is this supposed to do `data:social_sharing_buttons()`

Comment: Are you trying to pass the name of a PHP function to the PHP page and expecting the return of that function? If so, it's a great thought, but that won't work in that way. The data will be interpreted in php's `$_POST["key_name"])`. Someone will need to expound on this for an answer, though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I am aware, you can't. What you can do is have a handler file for your classes, so for example say we have this PHP class,

```
<?php
class Car {     
    function getCarType() {
        return "Super Car";
    }
}
?>
```

Then in your handler file,

```
<?php
require_once 'Car.php';

if(isset($_POST['getCarType'])) {
     $car = new Car();
     $result = $car->getCarType();

     echo $result;
}
?>
```

You'd post your AJAX request to the handler, you could make specific handlers for each request or you could have a generic AJAX handler, however that file could get quite big and hard to maintain.

In your case you'd have in that `data`,

```
"getSocialButtons" : true
```

Then in your AJAX handler file,

```
if (isset($_POST['getSocialButtons'])) {
    // Echo your function here.
}
```

Then you'd echo out the function within that `if statement` and using the success callback in your AJAX request do something like this.

```
document.getElementById("yourDivId").innerHTML = data
```

That is assuming you're using an ID. Adjust the JS function to suit you.

Answer (score 1):

Try to call that function social_sharing_buttons() like this in function.php:

```
$.ajax({
  type:"POST",
  url:"functions.php",
  data: {action: 'add'},
  success: function(data){
  $('.pp').html(data);
}
```

in functions.php

```
if(isset($_POST['action']) && !empty($_POST['action'])) {
 if($_POST['action'] == 'add') {
  echo social_sharing_buttons();
 }
}
```